# building tshark

Tags: porting, wireshark, tshark

I am porting tshark to a different OS.Can someone tell me which files/folders can be removed from the source code ? I am aware that GTK isnt required;but it would be great if i could do away with all the unnecessary files/folders right at the beginning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to mention. I'd port dumpcap first. It's used by tshark for capturing.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone tell me which files/folders can be removed from the source code ?

`ui/gtk` and, if you have it, `ui/qt`.  Do not remove anything else under `ui`; at least some of that code is shared between TShark and the {GTK+,Qt} versions of Wireshark, and the code in `ui/cli` is the tap code for TShark.

`help` is Wireshark-specific, so you can probably remove that.

`image` is necessary if you're building for Windows (it arguably shouldn't contain both images for the GUI and .rc.in files for the Windows resource compiler, but maybe that makes referring to icons in `image` more complicated).

You could perhaps also remove `doc` and `docbook` if you don't plan to build any documentation.

You could perhaps remove `test` if you're not going to run tests, and `packaging` and `debian` if this OS isn't Windows or some flavor of UN*X for which Wireshark provides packaging mechanisms.

I don't know whether any of the autoconf or CMake stuff will break if you remove them, however.  Unless you're running low on disk space, I'd leave all the directories and files in the source tree there, and just not bother porting the files that you don't need.